# Get soft deleted records using Nestjs and TypeOrmQueryService

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to get soft deleted records (`deletedAt` column) when using `query` from `TypeOrmQueryService` but looks like there is no way to do that. I know that I can use `withDeleted` if I use `find` or `findOne` but I cannot switch to these methods or use a query builder since it would require a lot of changed in the front-end.

```
@QueryService(Patient)
export class PatientQueryService extends TypeOrmQueryService<Patient> {
    constructor(@InjectRepository(Patient) repo: Repository<Patient>) {
        super(repo);
    }

    async getOnePatient(currentUser: User, patientId: number) {

        const result = await super.query({
            paging: { limit: 1 },
            filter: { id: { eq: 1 } },
        });
        
    }
}
```